# Почему не получается типизировать стейт?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Сейчас делаю приложение в связке реакт + тс, на основную страницу получаю список разных валют по апи которые идут блок за блоком но хочу чтоб при нажатии на блок мне открывалась страница с более подробной информацией об этой валюте. Все вышло но столкнулся с проблемой типизации стейта. С any все работает но хочется сделать нормально)

```js
const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState<any>({}); //ожидаю обьект с сервера 

 const fetchCurrency = async function () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<any>(url);
      setCurrency(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Код выше работает, данные с сервера приходят и можно продолжать но хочется типизировать стейт и запрос как нужно.

Кодпен с типизацией обьекта который я ожидаю с сервера(интерфесы сделаны при помощи конвертера поэтому ошибок быть не должно) :
https://codepen.io/IvaLu/pen/JjZjMgo?editors=0010

Далее я типизирую стейт и запрос но уже вылазит ошибка

```js
const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState<Pokedex>({}); //ожидаю обьект с сервера 

 const fetchCurrency = async function () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<Pokedex>(url);
      setCurrency(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Ошибка при типизации стейта:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pokedex | (() => Pokedex)'.

Можно исправить и написать так (но это костыли и прощк уже везде any) :

```js
const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState<Pokedex | any>({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Еще думал положить в обьект null:

```js
const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState<Pokedex | null>(null);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Object is possibly 'null'

Comment: В интерфейсе `Pokedex` все поля обязательны, поэтому объект `{}` не совместим с типом `Pokedex`. Попробуйте сделать все поля необязательными

Comment: Работает, благодарю